# Kafka-spark Streaming processing jobs synchronically

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, confluent-platform

Im trying a simple test where i use Kafka-connect and spark

I wrote a custom kafka-connect that creates this source record

```
SourceRecord sr = new SourceRecord(null,
                    null,
                    destTopic,
                   Schema.STRING_SCHEMA,
                    cleanPath);
```

in the spark i receive this message like this

```
val kafkaConsumerParams = Map[String, String](
      "metadata.broker.list" -> prop.getProperty("kafka_host"),
      "zookeeper.connect" -> prop.getProperty("zookeeper_host"),
      "group.id" -> prop.getProperty("kafka_group_id"),
      "schema.registry.url" -> prop.getProperty("schema_registry_url"),
      "auto.offset.reset" -> prop.getProperty("auto_offset_reset")
    )
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaConsumerParams, topicsSet)

val ds = messages.foreachRDD(rdd => {
          val toPrint = rdd.map(t => {
            val file_path = t._2

            val startTime = DateTime.now()


            Thread.sleep(1000 * 60)
            1
      }).sum()
        LogUtils.getLogger(classOf[DeviceManager]).info(" toPrint = " + toPrint +" (number of flows calculated)")
      })
    }
```

when i use the connector to send multiple message to the desired topic ( in my test it had 6 partitions)
The sleep thread gets all the messages, but preforms them synchronically instead of asynchronically.

When i create a simple test producer, the sleeps are done asynchronically.

I Also created 2 simple consumers, and tried both the connector and a producer, and both task were consumed asynchronically
which means my problems lays with the way the spark is receiving the messages sent from the connector. 
I cant figure why the tasks are not acting the same way as they do when i send it from a producer.

i even printed the record the spark recieves and they are exactly the same

producer sent record

```
1: {partition=2, offset=11, value=something, key=null}
2: {partition=5, offset=9, value=something2, key=null}
```

connect sent record

```
1: {partition=3, offset=9, value=something, key=null}
```

the versions used in my projects are

```
    <scala.version>2.11.7</scala.version>
    <confluent.version>4.0.0</confluent.version>
    <kafka.version>1.0.0</kafka.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spark.version>2.0.0</spark.version>
```

dependencies

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
            <scope>${global.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-connect-avro-converter</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
            <scope>${global.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect-api</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: If you're using Spark2, you need to update `<version>1.6.3</version>` in your POM to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot run Spark-Kafka streaming jobs asynchronously. But we can run them in parallel, as Kafka consumer(s) do. For that, we need to set following configuration in `SparkConf()`:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs","4")
```

By default, its value is `"1"`. But we can override it to a higher value.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It does, in addition, ive added a few more configuration to achieve exactly what i wanted. by setting the paramaters "spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate" and "spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition" to 1 as well as the kafka topic partition to 1, i managed to achive the behaviour i was looking for. that way, i "relieve" kafka from its partitioning duties and let the spark do it by himself. now  for each message received from kafka the spark sends it to any of his workers and its done in parallel, with the "spark.streaming.concurrentJobs" limit of course.